# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException in android 4.0

Tags: android, eclipse

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Signin extends Activity {

    EditText edt_mail, edt_password;
    Button btn_login, btn_pass, btn_reg, btn_forget;
    ImageView iv1, iv2;
    String strmail, strpassword, strres;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signin);

        btn_forget = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnforget);

        edt_mail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_Username);
        edt_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_Password);

        btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
        btn_pass = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncancel);
        btn_reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReg);
        iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgfacebook);
        iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgtwitter);
        btn_forget.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Signin.this, ForgetPassword.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        iv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Signin.this, Twitter.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Signin.this, Facebook.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        btn_reg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Signin.this, Signup.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        btn_pass.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                cleartext();
            }

            public void cleartext() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                edt_mail.setText("");
                edt_password.setText("");
            }
        });

        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (!edt_mail.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                    if (!edt_password.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                        try {
                            if (CheckConnection()) {
                                // new GetAccess().execute("");
                                getLogin();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        Signin.this,
                                        "Please check your internet connection",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(Signin.this,
                                    "Error caught = " + e.toString(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "please enter Password",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "please enter Username",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }

            private boolean CheckConnection() {
                final ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (activeNetwork != null
                        && activeNetwork.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    // notify user you are online
                    // System.out.println("Internet connected = 1");
                    return true;

                } else {
                    // notify user you are not online
                    // System.out.println("Internet not connected = 0");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please check your internet connection ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;

                }
            }
        });

    }

    public boolean CheckConnection() {
        final ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetwork != null
                && activeNetwork.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            // notify user you are online
            // System.out.println("Internet connected = 1");
            return true;
        } else {
            // notify user you are not online
            System.out.println("Internet not connected = 0");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please check your internet connection ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;

        }

    }

    private void loadList() {

        /*
         * ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
         * MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, eventlist);
         * view.setAdapter(adapter);
         */

        Intent intent = new Intent(Signin.this, MainList.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void getLogin() {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "my link");
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            // nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", edt_mail
                    .getText().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", edt_password
                    .getText().toString().trim()));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();

            // EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
            String strres = convertStreamToString(inputStream);

            if (!strres.toString().trim().equals("0")) {
                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "Successfully logged in ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Signin.this, NewMainList.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            }

            else if (strres.toString().trim().equals("0")) {
                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "Invalid login and password",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            System.out.println("Response = " + strres);

            // username.setText("");
            // password.setText("");// clear text box
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public String convertStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
            throws IOException {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line).append("\n");
                }
            } finally {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } else {
            return "";
        }

    }

    public class GetAccess extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(Signin.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Please wait");
            dialog.setMessage("Getting login access");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            getLogin();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            dialog.dismiss();
            setSession();
            loadList();

            // System.out.println(result);

        }

        private void setSession() {
            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("CurrentUser",
                    MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("Save", edt_mail.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("Save1", edt_password.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("Save2", strres.toString().trim());
            System.out.println("Response = " + strres);

            editor.commit();
            edt_mail.setText("");
            edt_password.setText("");

        }
    }

}
```

Note: this code work perfect in android 2.3 emulator and devices. but when i run this code in android 4.0 or higher. it give me force close error. please help to get out of this.in logcat, it display android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException error.. how can i fix this issue..???

Comment: why u comment  `new GetAccess().execute("");` line?

Answer (score 3):

Your error explains itself...

In older versions of AndroidOS you were able to run networking on the UI thread, which, if timed out, would cause your app to stop responding. To solve this, newer versions of Android no longer suppoer running network requests on the UI thread, you now need to do it in Threads or AsyncTasks.

This line:
`HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);` needs to be in a thread that is not running the UI.

```
new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        //TODO Run network requests here.
        getLogin();
    }
}.start();
```

Why this happens... Android runs something which can be refereed to as a WatchDog, which in laymans terms, is part of the code that links your code to Android. This timer will every so often communicate with your app and the OS to make sure that everything is running correctly and that nothing has crashed. If you run a network request on the UI Thread, which is the same thread that runs the WatchDog timer, and your response times out, it will lock up your entire app, causing it to stop communicating with Android.

Comment: i already use asynctask dude. just watch my code properly.

Comment: I did not see that as I got to your onClickListener for btn_login, and you call getLogin() without the AsyncTask. I use Threads instead of Async in all of my code, so I may be mis reading the code, where exactly do you invoke the AsyncTask?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have any network connection on your Main Thread. This means you need to move it to another Thread, via a Thread or an AsyncTask.

This means you need to do this to your getLogin() method. It is not legal to call **any** processing of a network connection in the Main Thread.

Answer (score 1):

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


add this lines after setcontentview(R.layout.main);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

I have changed. removed `Toast` in   `doInBackground()` add added into `onPostExecute()`.

```
  public class Signin extends Activity {

EditText edt_mail, edt_password;
Button btn_login, btn_pass, btn_reg, btn_forget;
ImageView iv1, iv2;
String strmail, strpassword, strres;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signin);

    btn_forget = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnforget);

    edt_mail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_Username);
    edt_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_Password);

    btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
    btn_pass = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncancel);
    btn_reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReg);
    iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgfacebook);
    iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgtwitter);
    btn_forget.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    ForgetPassword.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    iv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Twitter.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Facebook.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    btn_reg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Signup.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    btn_pass.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            cleartext();
        }

        public void cleartext() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            edt_mail.setText("");
            edt_password.setText("");
        }
    });

    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!edt_mail.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                if (!edt_password.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                    try {
                        if (CheckConnection()) {
                            new GetAccess().execute();
                            // getLogin();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    MainActivity.this,
                                    "Please check your internet connection",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "Error caught = " + e.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "please enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "please enter Username",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }

        private boolean CheckConnection() {
            final ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (activeNetwork != null
                    && activeNetwork.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                // notify user you are online
                // System.out.println("Internet connected = 1");
                return true;

            } else {
                // notify user you are not online
                // System.out.println("Internet not connected = 0");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please check your internet connection ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;

            }
        }
    });

}

public boolean CheckConnection() {
    final ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null
            && activeNetwork.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
        // notify user you are online
        // System.out.println("Internet connected = 1");
        return true;
    } else {
        // notify user you are not online
        System.out.println("Internet not connected = 0");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Please check your internet connection ",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;

    }

}

private void loadList() {

    /*
     * ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
     * MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, eventlist);
     * view.setAdapter(adapter);
     */

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainList.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

public void getLogin() {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("my link");
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        // nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", edt_mail
                .getText().toString().trim()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", edt_password
                .getText().toString().trim()));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();

        // EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
        strres = convertStreamToString(inputStream);

        System.out.println("Response = " + strres);

        // username.setText("");
        // password.setText("");// clear text box
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public String convertStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
        throws IOException {
    if (inputStream != null) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } finally {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } else {
        return "";
    }

}

public class GetAccess extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Please wait");
        dialog.setMessage("Getting login access");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        getLogin();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
        setSession();
        loadList();
        if (!strres.toString().trim().equals("0")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully logged in ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewMainList.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }

        else if (strres.toString().trim().equals("0")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid login and password",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // System.out.println(result);

    }

    private void setSession() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("CurrentUser",
                MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("Save", edt_mail.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("Save1", edt_password.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("Save2", strres.toString().trim());
        System.out.println("Response = " + strres);

        editor.commit();
        edt_mail.setText("");
        edt_password.setText("");

    }
}

}
```

Comment: not working.. but i got my solution..